# Get the last for loop variable value

Tags: php

I want to display the last modified variable outside the for loop

Code:

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++ )
{
$pm_discussion = $_POST['pm_discussion'.$i];
 $pm_update = $_POST['pm_update'.$i];
 $pm_reports = $_POST['pm_reports'.$i];
 $pm_informed = $_POST['pm_informed'.$i];
 $pm_complete = $_POST['pm_complete'.$i];

    }

 **echo $pm_discussion;**
```

For example:

$i inside the for loop having values from 1 to 6.

Then it should display $pm_discussion = **$_POST['pm_discussion'.$i];**

The above **$i** should be **6**.

Comment: last means after that all the fields will be empty?

Comment: than what is the problem you are facing ? Be clear

Comment: I thought I understood what you are saying...but I reread and I don't know what you are asking or what your issue is...

Comment: If you only want to show `pm_xxx6` then why are you using the loop at all?

Comment: I just want to display the variable value

Comment: Loop is for another purpose. And for my current requirement i just want to display the last modified variable value pm_xxx6

Comment: The `$i` value is retained after the loop so you echo what you have in your example. Did that not work or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code.

```
$temp='';
for( $i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++ )
{

$pm_discussion = $_POST['pm_discussion'.$i];
 $pm_update = $_POST['pm_update'.$i];
 $pm_reports = $_POST['pm_reports'.$i];
 $pm_informed = $_POST['pm_informed'.$i];
 $pm_complete = $_POST['pm_complete'.$i];
 if($pm_discussion!='')
    $temp = $pm_discussion;
 }
echo $temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will alsays store the last non empty value to the variable -

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++ )
{
     if (!empty($_POST['pm_discussion'.$i])) {
         $pm_discussion = $_POST['pm_discussion'.$i];
     }
     if (!empty($_POST['pm_update'.$i])) {
         $pm_update = $_POST['pm_update'.$i];
     }
     if (!empty($_POST['pm_reports'.$i])) {
         $pm_reports = $_POST['pm_reports'.$i];
     }
     if (!empty($_POST['pm_informed'.$i])) {
         $pm_informed = $_POST['pm_informed'.$i];
     }
     if (!empty($_POST['pm_complete'.$i])) {
         $pm_complete = $_POST['pm_complete'.$i];
     }
}
echo $pm_discussion;
```